# Iteration over ExecutionResult in neo4j is not working

Tags: neo4j

I am somehow new for neo4j. I have been working on a code which looks like the following

```
String query = String.format("start a = node:ids({id}) match a-[e]->b return "
                + "a.id, b.id, e;", Constants.ID_NAME_INDEX);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap();
params.put("id, "id:" + id);
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
ExecutionResult rs = engine.execute(query, params);
for (Map<String, Object> row : rs) {
        for (Entry<String, Object> column : row.entrySet()) {
            String key = column.getKey();
            String value = column.getValue().toString();
            switch (key) {
                case "a.id":
                    \\Some operation here
                    break;
                case "b.id":
                    \\Some operation here
                    break;
                case "e":
                    \\Some operation here
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and it used to work properly. For some reason it stops working properly.
My problem is, after the query is executed, even though I can see that there are hundreds of results returned through debugging; the program skips the iteration over the result set and jump to the last line as if there is not result in the Iterator.

What could be the possible logic flaw I made?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? 1.8, 1.9 or 2.0?

Comment: I am using Neo4j 1.8.2 community Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give this a try, because I had faced a very similar issue once -

Immediately after you execute the query, i.e. after the line `ExecutionResult rs = engine.execute(query, params);`

call *hasNext()* i.e.

> rs.hasNext();

just before calling the *for* loop. I believe this is because the results are lazily force fetched once you call *hasNext()*

Comment: Execution result does not have hasNext?!